# Run multiple settimeout or showit functions on different page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

*Note: I am not a developer. More of a hobbyist (read n00b).
I have tried searching for an answer to this but so far have not found anything that provides an answer to this specific scenario.*

I know this is relatively basic but, I am trying to create a page with three hidden elements that are revealed either after a time delay or a mouse click. What I am struggling with is getting all three elements to run on the same page.

> Required:
>   Element 1: Hidden image to be revealed 10 seconds after page load
>   Element 2: Hidden div to be revealed 10 minutes after page load
>   Element 3: Button image *inside element 2*, when clicked reveals another hidden div

I am using the following setTimeout function to reveal element 1, but I can't get a second setTimeout command to run after this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var pop=10;
function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "block";
}
setTimeout(showIt, 10000);
</script>
```

I tried repeating this code for the second element changing the Element ID to "hid2" but it will not run. Do I need to use a cleartimeout function to end the first settimeout?

I then need some code for element 3 to run on a mouse click after element 2.

Getting all three bits of JS to play nicely together seems to be beyond me. 
Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're asking for.

```
<img id="hid" src="img/darkred.jpg" style="width: 20px; display: none;"/>
<div id="hid2" style="display: none;">div 2
    <input type="button" value="show div3"/>
</div>
<div id="hid3" style="display: none;">div 3</div>


function showIt(hid) {
    document.getElementById(hid).style.display = "block";
}

function revealEl(id, delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
        showIt(id);
    }, delay);
}

revealEl("hid", 4000);
revealEl("hid2", 6000);

$("#hid2 input"").on("click", function(){
    showIt("hid3");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jEremyB Should $("#hid2 input"") be $("#hid2 input")? Testing in jsFiddle, I just can't get div 3 to show when clicking the button http://jsfiddle.net/n26qN. Any ideas?

Comment: That selector may need to change to match your html. Try adding an id to the button you want to use to show div 3. For example, id="showDiv3", then change the selector to $("#showDiv3"). Test the selector independently to make sure it's matching the expected target.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried to do what you suggested but just can't get it to work. Could you please check my code and possibly tweak it to make it run? http://jsfiddle.net/n26qN/1/ Sorry for my n00b-ness.

Comment: It looks like jQuery isn't loaded. Add this to the page <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks @jEremyB. I added the script line to the top of my html, but it hasn't made any difference I'm afraid.  I now have two versions of your code with jQuery manually added.   
1.Original version - http://jsfiddle.net/n26qN/2/.  
2. Version with updated selector  - http://jsfiddle.net/n26qN/3/.  
Unfortunately neither seem to be showing div 3 onclick.  Sorry, but could I ask you to take one more look? I'm just hitting and hoping at this point.

Comment: Ok. Got it working. The link to jquery 1.10.2 wasn't valid. I added // to the beginning and now it works. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I'd like to select your answer as the accepted answer but it needs to be corrected as per http://jsfiddle.net/n26qN/4/. What is SOF etiquette here? If you edit yur code above, then all of the subsequent conversation will be redundant. Do you want to answer the question again (with revisions) and I can accept that answer? Not sure how it's meant to work.

Comment: Please be aware that you put the jquery tag on your question. This suggests that jquery is loaded correctly and it can be used in the answer.

Comment: Hi @jEremyB Unfortunately I've discovered that manually calling jQuery 1.10.2 prevents our main video lightbox (fancybox) from running. Ver 1.10.2 is already loaded in the header pointing to .../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'> and I suspect that manually calling it again causes a conflict. If I remove it from the code my lightbox works but my onclick event does not. If I add it back my lightbox fails. If version 1.10.2 is already in header then why isn't it working without manually calling the jQuery? Any suggestions? I'm really stuck now :(

Comment: Also, I did not understand what you meant by "Please be aware that you put the jquery tag on your question." Can you be more specific? Does it relate to the latest issue?

Comment: When debugging... with the jquery called manually I get 'TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function'. With the manual call removed I get 'TypeError: $ is not a function' relating to this line '$("#showDiv3").on("click", function () {'

Comment: I replaced $("#showDiv3") with jQuery("#showDiv3") and now it works without having to manually call jQuery. I don't understand why this works... is this good practice? Am I likely to run into any issues doing this?